# why the h2 mvstore off heap store file not created

Tags: caching, h2

I use the following code to try MVStore off heap store:

```
    OffHeapStore offHeap = new OffHeapStore();
    MVStore s = new MVStore.Builder().fileName("c:\\temp\\h2.cache").fileStore(offHeap).open();
    int count = 100;
    Map<Integer, String> map1 = s.openMap("u1");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       map1.put(i, "Hello " + i);
    }
    s.commit();
    int size1 = map1.size();
    s.close();
    System.out.println("=====");
    MVStore s2 = new MVStore.Builder().fileStore(offHeap).open();
    map1 = s2.openMap("u1");
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        System.out.println("M1>"+i+","+map1.get(i));
    }
    s2.close();
```

The code seems to work.  After the code executes, the file "c:\temp\h2.cache" is not created.  Why?

Comment: The data put into the map are supposed to be saved to the specified file.  I don't understand why the data do persist but the file is not created.

Answer (score 1):

`OffHeapStore` is located in the memory of the process, but outside of Java heap. When you use custom `.fileStore(something)`, `.fileName(something)` is silently ignored.

If you want to store data on the disk, you need to remove initialization of `OffHeapStore`, both `.fileStore(offHeap)` calls and add missing `.fileName("c:\\temp\\h2.cache")` call to the second `MVStore.Builder()`.

Comment: Follow your answer, I correct the code.  Change the line to MVStore s = new MVStore.Builder().fileName("c:\\temp\\h2.cache").open(); and it works as expected.  Thanks for your help!